# Tkinterでウィンドウを消すときにコマンドを実行したい

Tags: python, python3, tkinter, gui

`Toplevel`のウィンドウを消すときにコマンドを実行したい。
`tk.Tk()`のウィンドウなら、`__del__`を上書きすればいいと思うが、`Toplevel`でそうやると、メインウィンドウを消したときに実行されてしまう。
自分で別にボタンを作ってもいいと思うが、タイトルバーの削除ボタンで実行できないか。

Comment: こうした記事に情報があります。[Tkinter イベントのバインディング の続き - Tkinter Event and binding](https://cassiopeia.hatenadiary.org/entry/20070822/1187712650), [How do I handle the window close event in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111155/9014308) それらで出来ない事を希望しているなら、何がどう違うのかその詳細を追記してみてください。

Comment: <Toplevel>.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", <fnc>)でいけました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

以下の記述でいけました。

```
<Toplevel>.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", <fnc>)
```